# Whiteboard software recomendation for teaching Physics online

Tags: whiteboard

I'm looking for a good digital whiteboard software to teach Physics online. I currently use Microsoft Whiteboard, and I find it quite convenient except when it comes to making drawings and diagrams. It does not allow to insert straight lines, arrows or geometric figures, so it becomes extremely awkward to draw diagrams like the one in the image.

Could someone recommend an alternative that would allow me to make drawings more effectively?

[image: w]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one - https://awwapp.com.
It's very simple and functional: multiple colors, incredibly simple to invite students to join the board, cross-platform (any student with an internet connection can use it, and it works in every browser, as far as I can tell), and there is an option to save the images you create so you and your students can have material for reference later. And it's completely free =)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not what you are looking for but can I suggest taking a look at using [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) - the book "[Teaching and Learning with Jupyter](https://jupyter4edu.github.io/jupyter-edu-book/)" is full of tips and tricks.